# How to implement JOIN in Sequelize

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I have three tables, and the structure is described as follows:

User table contains fields: `id`, `name`, `date_created`

Library table contains fields: `id`, `capacity`, `date_created`, `user_id`

user_id is a foreign key for User table and each instance of Library must belong to a user.

The last table is Books table which contains fields: `id`, `status`, `date_created`, `library_id`.

library_id is a foreign key for Library table and each instance of a book must belong to a Library.

What I'm trying to achieve is a way to query the DB for all instances of a book that belongs to user and has a status of for example: `borrowed`

Comment: First use this : http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html

Comment: @VivekDoshi I have done the necessary association

Answer (score 4):

To implement joins first you need to establish associations between sequelize models.
So, in your case

```js
models.Library.hasMany(models.Books, {
    foreignKey: 'library_id'
})

models.Books.belongsTo(models.Library, {
    foreignKey: 'library_id'
})

models.Library.belongsTo(models.User, {
    foreignKey: 'user_id'
})

models.User.hasMany(models.Library, {
    foreignKey: 'user_id'
})
```

here, `models`
is a sequelize instance.
You can find more about sequelize associaitions here http: //docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html

Now, To find all instances of Books that belongs to User

```js
models.User.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: models.Library,
        required: true, // do an INNER Join 
        include: [{
            model: models.Books,
            required: true,
            where: {
                status: 'borrowed'
            }
        }] t
    }],
    where: {
       user_id: 'some_user_id'
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `include` is what you need , please check below query :

```
Books.findAll({
    include : { //<------ By this you can use association
        model : User ,
        where : { id : YOUR_USER_ID }
    },
    where : { status : 'borrowed' }    
}).then(books => {
    if(books.length > 0) {
        console.log(books);
    } else {
        console.log("No books found");
    }
})
```

Comment: You need to setup associations first

Comment: Ohh Okay my bad sorry :)